# Time complexity of iterating through python's Collections.counter

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

What is the time complexity to `iteritems()` through key-value elements of `Collections.Counter` in python:

```
Count = Counter()
for i in "string":
    Count[i]+=1
for key, value in Count().iteritems():
    print k, v
```

Comment: First of all, you're better off doing `Count = Counter("string")`. Secondly, the time complexity of the `iteritems` call in question would be `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of distinct characters in `string`

Comment: You could test it with [```timeit```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#module-timeit).  https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity.

Comment: @wwii That page doesn't mention Counter, though.

Comment: @StefanPochmann ```collections.Counter``` inherits from ```dict```. Make a ```Counter``` object and check - ```isinstance(counter_obj, dict)```.

Comment: @wwii Yes, but that was not clear. And more importantly, Counter *could* re-implement methods and change the complexities.

Comment: @wwii I might test it in a wrong way. A way that makes it look O(n) even though it might be less efficient in general, in tests I didn't think of.

Comment: The docs are pretty clear that it is a, subclass of, ```dict``` with added functionality.  That said, I doubt they rewrote any of the ```dict``` *stuff* to add that functionality.  The docs say you can actually use it as a regular dictionary so I imagine that the item access is the same as a ```dict```.  Only way to prove it would be to time the iteration with varying number of keys.